# How to update two different rows by one query?

Tags: mysql, sql, logical-operators

Here is my table:

```
// mytable

+----+------+
| id | num  |
+----+------+
| 1  | 400  |
| 2  | 200  |
| 3  | 200  |
| 4  | 250  |
+----+------+
```

And here is expected result:

```
+----+------+
| id | num  |
+----+------+
| 1  | 390  |
| 2  | 200  |
| 3  | 220  |
| 4  | 250  |
+----+------+
```

As you see, I've subtracted `10` where `id = 1`, and I've added `20` where `id = 3`

Here is my query:

```
UPDATE mytable SET num = num +/- (CASE WHEN num = 1 THEN 10 WHEN num = 3 THEN 20 END)
WHERE id IN (1,3)
```

How can I manage `+ or -` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use a negative number in the case statement:

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET num = num + CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN -10 ELSE 20 END
WHERE id IN (1,3)
```